# To get the computed value of a div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height

I have 3 `li` under `ul`. Now I want to know the height of `li`. I do not give height to the `li`. But I want the computed height of `li`. When I saw the firebug I found the computed height of `li` is 14px. But after use the `.height()` of jQuery, I got 0px height of that `li`.

How can I get the computed value height of `li`?

I tried like the following snippet but I can't get the height:

```
var $ht = jQuery("#access ul ul ul a").height();
console.log($ht);
```

Comment: Console log the element, as you're probably not hitting the target.

Comment: you ask for li height, but your code measures some oddly nested anchor

Comment: do `console.log($("#access ul ul ul a"))` to see if it returns an actual element or undefined.

Comment: I got the actual element, but i cant get the computed value of that element. My problem is not the element selecting. i got an error if use console.log($("#access ul ul ul a")) Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function

Comment: That error message means jQuery is'nt loaded. You either forgot to wrap the code in document.ready, or did'nt properly load the jQuery file.

Comment: If wrapping your code in $(function () { //code }) produces the error then either jQuery is not loaded or some other script redefined $.

Answer (score 2):

If your `<a>` is empty then `height()` appropriately yields 0. If you would like the height of the `<li>` then change the code to:

```
var $ht = jQuery("#access ul li li li").height();
console.log($ht);
```

If your `<li>` has margins and paddings you want included in the calculations, then use the following:

```
var $ht = jQuery("#access ul li li li").outerHeight(true);
console.log($ht);
```

Answer (score -1):

try `console.log($("#access ul ul ul a").css("height"));`

Comment: I want the computed height, which is display in the firebug.